# sklearn.KNeighborsClassifier gives very low accuracy score

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am new to machine learning.

I created a data, random numbers in two sets. I am trying how to find a sample, however when doing following, I receive very low accuracy score:

```
from random import randint as R
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier as KNC
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split as tts
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


a = [R(100,200) for x in range(100)] 

b = [R(1000,2000) for x in range(100)] 

c = a+b 

X = np.array(c).reshape(len(c),1) 
y = np.arange(len(c)) 


train_X, test_X, train_y,test_y = tts(X,y,test_size=0.4)



mimi = KNC()
mimi.fit(train_X, train_y) 

y__pred = mimi.predict(train_X)
print(accuracy_score(train_y,y__pred))
print(mimi.score(train_X,train_y))
```

I receive a result of 0.18... What exactly does this mean? That a prediction score is just 18%? Please, can you explain to me in most simple way. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: For what it's worth, think about what you said above: "I created ... data, random numbers in two sets (**technically not sets, lists**)." You're trying to build a classifier off of **random** relationships. Why would you expect, on average, to achieve anything remotely accurate if there's not necessarily an inherent relationship between your inputs and output? I would suggest finding one of the *many* open "intro to machine learning"-type datasets out there and use that instead of generating random data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `y = np.arange(len(c))` you have `c` different classes (here 200 classes) with only one example for each class. Learning the nearest neighbors on such a setup does not have any sense.

What you want (If I'm guessing right) is to have one class for data `a` and another class for data `b`.
Change `y` to:

```
y = np.concatenate([[0] *len(a), [1] *len(b)])
```

You'll see that you obtain an accuracy score of 1.0, which means that you successfully classify all your testing example.